# What's the difference between boost::io_service poll_one and run_one?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

> io_service::poll_one Run the io_service object's event processing loop
>   to execute one ready handler.

vs

> io_service::run_one Run the io_service object's event processing loop
>   to execute at most one handler.

From that explanation it would seem poll_one could execute more than one handler? Does run_one or poll_one use any thread that's called run() or only the thread that calls poll_one/run_one?

The documentation for ASIO is very sparse.

Comment: one executes one READY handler, the other executes one handler (ready or not).

Comment: ok, what's the distinction between a READY handler and one that's not?

Comment: if you have a socket and the handler's job is to read something out of it, then a ready handler is one which is attached to a non-empty socket (so you don't have to wait for the data to come from the net)

Comment: So when would you want to execute a non-ready handler?

Comment: This is up to the application in hand.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`poll_one` will return immediately (non-blocking) in case there is no event to process.

`run_one` will block the calling thread until one event is ready to process.

You could also check some documentation [here](http://think-async.com/)

Comment: So the documentation for run_one should read "blocks until it executes exactly one handler" vs "executes at most one handler"?

Comment: It's confusing. "At most" here implies 0..1 but if it blocks until it processes an event, when can it ever return having processed 0 events?

Comment: In case the service is closed.