# What is the definition of a boost::asio::io_service ready handler?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to understand the difference between io_service's poll()/poll_one() and run()/run_one(). The difference as stated in the documentation is that poll() executes ready handlers as opposed to run() which executes any handler.

But nowhere in the boost documentation could I find the definition of a 'ready handler'.

A valid answer to this question is one able to show, preferably with a code example, the difference between a ready and non-ready handler and the difference between how poll() and run() executes it.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727568/whats-the-difference-between-boostio-service-poll-one-and-run-one

Comment: yes, I am aware of that question. It is related, yet it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);

    timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    timer.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code& err)
                     { std::cout << (err ? "error" : "okay")
                     ;});

    //io_service.poll_one(); 
    io_service.run_one();
}
```

If you use `io_service.poll_one();` you will most likely not see any output because the timer has not elapsed yet. `ready handler` simply means a handle that is ready to run (such as when a timer elapses or an operation finishes, etc.). However, if you use  `io_service.run_one();` this call will block until the timer finishes and execute the handler.

Comment: I upvoted both yours and Arne Mertz's answers, they're both very eloquent and explain the term equally well. I've accepted your answer because of the code sample. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 11):

A "ready handler" is a handler that is ready to be executed. If you have issued an asynchronous call, it gets executed in the background and its handler becomes ready when the async call is done. Before that, the handler is pending, but not ready.

- `poll_one` executes one ready handler if there is any.
- `poll` executes all ready handlers, but not the pending. Both poll versions return immediately after the execution of the handlers.
- `run_one` executes a ready handler if there is one, if not it waits for the first pending handler to become ready, meaning it blocks.
- `run` executes and waits, until there are neither ready nor pending handlers. After it returns, the io_servie is in stopped state.

See also [Boost::Asio : io_service.run() vs poll() or how do I integrate boost::asio in mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705411/boostasio-io-service-run-vs-poll-or-how-do-i-integrate-boostasio-in-ma)